# How to Identify Complexity of IBM ODM Rules Based Applications?

Tags: business-rules, ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

I would like to know, how the complexity of a rule based application can be measured?

Is there a standard way defined by IBM ?

or something with Function Point to measure the complexity of a software based application

Complexity can always be based on some parameters like the 1) Parameters being passed / 2) Number of Rules present / 3) database look ups / 4) Network Latency / 5)Ruleset Parsing Time / 6) Ruleset Execution Time / 7) Application Design / 8) Execution Unit Configuration /  9) Configure the XOM / 10) Asynchronous Ruleset Parsing / 11) Connection Pool Size / 12) RES Server Configuration / 13) XU Configuration / 14) Reduce Trace in Server Logs

Can someone please help me understand the standard way IBM does recommend it or is it decided by the application architect ?

Any and all Inputs are much appreciated... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined way of measuring the 'complexity' of an ODM application. However, you should make sure you use the correct topology for your needs (see the [Deployment Architecture](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.7.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.deploying/topics/tpc_ds_managing_env.html?lang=en) ODM documentation), and  the appropriate design decisions  for your performance requirements (See the ODM documentation at [Overview: What affects the performance of a Decision Server application](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.7.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/optimizing_topics/tpc_opt_perfscalability.html?lang=en) and [Improving the performance of Rule Execution Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.7.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.res.managing/topics/tpc_res_performance.html).)

There is also the [Improve performance for IBM ODM series](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/bpm/libraryview.jsp?search_by=Improve%20performance%20for%20IBM%20Operational%20Decision%20Manager) on developerWorks, which discusses in detail the possible configurations and their impact on performance, including the parameters you mentioned. dW Answers also has a few entries on ODM performance listed in [Improve performance of ODM modules](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/174010/improve-performance-of-odm-modules.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and taking out your valuable time z_blue. The first 5 words did tell me there is no defined way but we do have rule designer to analyze the rule application and/or the decision center?

+1 for the answer

Comment: You can analyze your rules for consistency and completeness. However there is no analyzer for the 'complexity' of an ODM application available as of now.

Comment: This post includes everything!

Answer (score 1):

For me there are 3 key factors:

- Integrations with other applications (SOA approach for ws -ESB, BPM, .net, etc)
- Programming level, if you need to use a lot of functions for the rules (fors, maps, vectors, etc)
- Rule projects volume, how many decision services you would have.

Hope this help you.

Comment: It definitely helps to be having valuable suggestions. Will study our application accordingly. Is there any tool that determines the level of complexity, for these applications that you might be aware of??

Comment: there is no tool that I know of, but I recommend you to read this article (part1 of 2) if you have any BPM or SOA integrations in your solution: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1112_clark/1112_clark.html.
It also helps to understand the complexity of integrations at a technical level .